# Can a relationship type attribute be a derived attribute?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, eer-model

[image]

Is it possible to have this? Assuming there are many attributes in the relations A and B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we must remember that a derived attribute is a changing attribute that can be achieved by another, such as your age (current date - date of birth)

Yes, imagine this situation, you have the relationship of many to many students - course

We can say that a student will take a course that will start on January 3rd and last 8 weeks of effective classes, we can't put directly the attribute "end date" because this date could change (for example because of a strike, a pandemic) but we can put the start date and make the calculation.